# Why is True if foo else False faster then bool(foo)?

Tags: python, optimization

Why is it that according to the timeit.timeit function the code `boolean = True if foo else False` runs faster than the code `boolean = bool(foo)`?

How is it that the if statement is able to determine the trueness of foo faster then the bool function itself?

Why doesn't the bool function simply use the same mechanic?

And what is the purpose of the bool function when it can be outperformed by a factor of four by a different technique?

Or, is it so that I am misusing the timeit function and that bool(foo) is, in fact, faster?

```py
>>> timeit.timeit("boolean = True if foo else False", setup="foo='zon-zero'")
0.021019499999965774
>>> timeit.timeit("boolean = bool(foo)", setup="foo='zon-zero'")
0.0684856000000309
>>> timeit.timeit("boolean = True if foo else False", setup="foo=''")
0.019911300000103438
>>> timeit.timeit("boolean = bool(foo)", setup="foo=''")
0.09232059999999365
```

Looking at these results, `True if foo else False` seems to be four to five times faster than `bool(foo)`.

I suspect that the difference in speed is caused by the overhead of calling a function and that does indeed seem to be the case when I use the dis module.

```py
>>> dis.dis("boolean = True if foo else False")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (foo)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (True)
              6 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 10)
        >>    8 LOAD_CONST               1 (False)
        >>   10 STORE_NAME               1 (boolean)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("boolean = bool(foo)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (bool)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (foo)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 STORE_NAME               2 (boolean)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

According to the dis module, than the difference between the two techniques is:

```
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (True)
              6 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 10)
        >>    8 LOAD_CONST               1 (False)
```

versus

```
              0 LOAD_NAME                1 (bool)

              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
```

which makes it look like either the call to a function is far too expensive for something as simple as determining a boolean value or the bool function has been written very inefficiently.
But that actually makes me wonder why anyone would use the bool function when it is this much slower and why the bool function even exists when python does not even seem to use it internally.

So, is the bool function slower because it has been written inefficiently, because of the function overhead, or because of a different reason?

And why would anyone use the bool function when a much faster and equally clear alternative is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Python documentation :

> **class bool( [ x ] )** 
>   Return a Boolean value, i.e. one of True or False. x is converted using the standard truth testing
>   procedure. If x is false or omitted, this returns False; otherwise it returns True. The bool class is a
>   subclass of int (see Numeric Types — int, float, complex). It cannot be subclassed further. Its only
>   instances are False and True

So, when you directly use the object itself (like foo), the interpreter uses its `foo.__bool__` property. But the bool function is a wrapper that again calls `foo.__bool__`
As you said, calling the function made it expensive.
And the use of bool is, there are certain situations where you need the boolean value of an object and need to refer it by a variable.

`x = bool(my_object)`
Writing `x = my_object` doesn't work.
Here its useful.
Sometimes bool(foo) is more readable where you can ignore small time lags.
You might be also interested in knowing that 
`x = {}`
is faster than 
`x = dict()`

Find out why... :)

Comment: I see, but is there a reason why I would choose to use `bool(foo)` over `True if foo else False`. When timeit.timeit claims `True if foo else False` to be much faster?

Comment: I answered that above too. There are certain situations, where you need to get the boolean value of an object. Mind the fact that booleans are not limited to if-else or loop blocks. They have other uses too. Take the simple context, where you need to print the boolean of an object, you can't write `print(if object)` the proper way is to use `print(bool(object))`

Comment: `bool(foo)` is shorter and more readable, which is preferable if this bit of code isn't a bottleneck in your program. Speed isn't everything.

Comment: @chepner yea that is another use. I thought of adding it, but forgot. Thanks